# How to use regular expressions in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I have the following text:

```
{"version":"0.0.1","build":"5d687795216a527f26c04c9c8da9551a72cb7fed","environment":"stage"}
```

How do I retrieve the 5d687795216a527f26c04c9c8da9551a72cb7fed from the text above in bash?

Comment: bash is a shell and has no concept of a regex. Instead you would need to use a program like grep.

Comment: I guess [like this](http://ideone.com/AxAEmB).

Comment: @DTSCode, incorrect; bash **does** have built-in regex support; that's what `[[ $string =~ $re ]]` is, matching the contents of `$foo` against the regular expression stored in `$re`. That said, it's the wrong tool for this particular job, which calls for `jq`, `jsawk`, or similar.

Comment: charles duffy: yeah I misspoke. I was more meaning bash itself, not the builtin tools like [[, if that makes sense

Comment: @DTSCode, ...but builtins are part of the shell; indeed, `[[` is not just a regular builtin (as `[` is), but is actually a keyword with its own parser-level syntax rules (thus its behavior of suppressing glob expansion and string-splitting, being able to behave differently based on whether individual characters were quoted/escaped, etc).

Comment: right, which is why I misspoke. I was attempting to form a differrentiation between the job of a shell and its builtin features

Comment: why do we have to put BASH_REMATCH in {} Why can't it be $BATCH_REMAIN[0]

Comment: @Jasmine, ...because how else will the shell know that the `[0]` is part of the expansion? Just like you can `echo "$hello[world]"` to print the contents of the variable `hello`, followed by the literal string `[world]`.

Answer (score 2):

What you have there is not just text but a structured data tree format known as JSON.

As such, you should process it with a JSON tool like `jq`:

```
echo '{"version":"0.0.1","build":"5d687795216a527f26c04c9c8da9551a72cb7fed","environment":"stage"}' \
    | jq -r '.build'
```